# How to set flag to true in list of feeds efficietly if user has liked the feed?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working for an app that is a kind of social media. On the home screen of the mobile application, I am showing a list of feeds created by all the users in the app with the pagination.

In response to the list of feeds API, **I want to set a flag in each feed object to indicate if a particular feed is liked by the currently logged-in user**.

Here is my Entity structure. (I am using relational database)

```
class Feed { 
    Interger feedId;
    Integer userId;
    String title;
    String content;
  
    @OneToMany
    List<FeedMedia> feedMedia;
}
```

**FeedMedia** Entity has **id, type, path, and ManyToOne relation with feed**.

```
class FeedLikes {
   Integer id;
   Integer userId;
   Integer feedId
}
```

I am fetching a list of feeds along with feed media using the below query:

```
select distinct f from Feed f left join fetch f.mediaList m where 1=1
```

Then to set the flag of if a particular feed is liked by that user, I am iterating the list of feeds and performing database query for each feed as shown below:

```
feedLikesRepository.existsByUserIdAndFeedId(user.getUserId(), feed.getFeedId())
```

If pagination size is n then I will get n feeds, and for those n feeds n queries need to be executed to set mentioned flag in my current approach.

**Is there any way to improve my current approach, so that I do not need to perform extra n queries?**

Note: I want to fetch list of feeds along with title,content,feedmedia and isLikedByUser flag.

Comment: you should fetch the "FeedLikes" along with "Feeds" by joining into that table by feed id.

Feed class should have one more field "Set<UserId> likedUsers"
then you will not to have query n times.

Comment: @Lucia In this case, I need to add "Set<FeedLikes> feedLikes" in Feed Entity. Can it cause a performance issue, because all the feedLikes objects related to that feed will be loaded for all the feeds? Also, I will need to iterate feedLikes objects for each feed to determine the value of that flag. I just want to confirm that this approach is better than the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Loading feedlikes at oneshot is better than loading them in a loop - which will avoid roundtrips to the DB.
Remember looping in JAVA is pretty fast. 
But DB query running inside a loop is pretty BAD, since DB query involves network roundtrips

Comment: @Lucia I think I should follow the approach you mentioned, it will be better than earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the approach discussed in the comments, one way I found is as :

I will pass the list of feeds which I got in my first query to the below
query,

`@Query("select fl.feedId from FeedLikes fl where fl.userId= :userId and fl.feed in :feeds") List<Object[]> findFeedsLikedByCurrentUser(List<Feed> feeds, Integer userId);`

From this list of feed Ids, it becomes easy and efficient to set the required flag.